# Pulling out lines which contain certain words exactly once

Tags: grep

I am trying to pull out lines in a tab delimited text file which contain all user-specified words exactly once (the sequence doesn't matter).

For example, I need to find lines which contain 'CA_', 'CS_', 'XV_' and 'JS_' exactly once.

[image]

Can I use grep for that?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution. Is that what you are trying to do?

```js
var rawString = 'CA_1234567 CA_R345335 CS_I8788765 CA_3456783 CS_0986887 CS_scaffolding2 CA_scaffolding3';

var valArr = rawString.split(' ');

//note: in real code, put CA, CA etc in an array and iterate

var CAItems = $.grep(valArr, function(val)
  {
    if (val.startsWith('CA'))
      {
        return val;
      }
  });

var CSItems = $.grep(valArr, function(val)
  {
    if (val.startsWith('CS'))
      {
        return val;
      }
  });


$('#CAValuesTxt').text(CAItems.join(' '))

$('#CSValuesTxt').text(CSItems.join(' '))


String.prototype.startsWith = function (prefix) {
    return this.indexOf(prefix) === 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>Values starting with CA: </label>
<label id='CAValuesTxt'></label>
<br/>
<br/>
<label>Values starting with CS: </label>
<label id='CSValuesTxt'></label>
```

I hope it helps!

Comment: Unfortunately I couldn't get it to work this way. I tried                                 'code' grep -E '[CA_\d+\sCB_\d+\sCM_\d+\sCS_\d+\sCT_\d+\sJD_\d+\sJF_\d+\sJI_\d+\sJPR_\d+\sJP_\d+\sJS_\d+\sMD_\d+\sPB_\d+\sXN_\d+\sXV_\d+]' infile > out.txt which should pull out all the lines with the exact sequence of search terms but it doesn't. Any ideas why not?

Comment: Updated the code with a simple demo. Please verify.